Get centroid xy of selected polygon feature for UTM
Building a Script Tool that will take a selected polygon feature iterating through a 1 deg x 1 deg grid feature class. The tool creates a new geodatabase with name from [GEOCELL] field of selected feature (N34W107.gdb). This works.
I need to create a new GDB Feature Dataset with UTM of the selected feature. I'm not sure how to get the centroid of the selected feature x,y into arcpy.GetUTMFromLocation.
layer1x1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer1x1, ['GEOCELL']) as geocell_cursor:
    for name in geocell_cursor:
        exp1 = "GEOCELL = '{}'".format(name[0])
        exp2 = "{}".format(name[0])
        gdbname = output + "/" + exp2 + ".gdb"
        
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer1x1, "NEW_SELECTION", exp1)
        
        arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(output, exp2)

        utm = arcpy.GetUTMFromLocation(x, y)
        arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(gdbname, "source_utm", utm)
        
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer1x1, "CLEAR_SELECTION")


I figured it out... added a SearchCursor for the selected feature layer row and centroid SHAPE@XY, and set row as the x, y variable. The creates a Feature Dataset with the correct UTM projection.
layer1x1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer1x1, ['GEOCELL']) as geocell_cursor:
    for name in geocell_cursor:
        exp1 = "GEOCELL = '{}'".format(name[0])
        exp2 = "{}".format(name[0])
        gdbname = output + "/" + exp2 + ".gdb"
        
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer1x1, "NEW_SELECTION", exp1)
        
        for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer1x1, ["SHAPE@XY"]):
            x, y = row[0]
        
        utm = arcpy.GetUTMFromLocation(x, y)
        
        arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(output, exp2)
        arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(gdbname, "source_utm", utm)
        
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer1x1, "CLEAR_SELECTION")

